# How to solve an unknown error: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method...setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I followed an online tutorial for creating a login/register activity using SQLite. The tutorial is only 4 months old, and I followed the tutorial exactly when I ran my app, it is not starting my Intent, and it gave me the following error:

> fatal exception main: .... caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference....

It was a textView, with an onClickListener, and I've changed it to a button...

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){//the error is on this line
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Stack trace please?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the initialization statement of register button

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.benvanj.android.homehr.Login.onCreate(Login.java:32)

Comment: Saurav Kumar... thanks there was a problem, when I changed the Textview to a buttton I didn't change the initialisation, but now i'm getting this error:      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.benvanj.android.homehr.Login.onCreate(Login.java:32)

Comment: like this:??? register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register); was there

Comment: Is your line setContentView(R.layout.layoutName) before the initialization statement

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!!!! thanks Saurav!!!!!

Comment: let @SauravKumar create an answer, then you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Was the problem really what I said

Answer (score 2):

you must use initialization before this code

intializ example :

Button register= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

Comment: Button register;                   register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);.... yip was there...